# Get Reference table of a field in Scope

Tags: javascript, servicenow

How do I get all fields with a reference to sys_user on a record?

As I'm in a scope I can't use the function `getFields()`

What I need to do is loop trough every field on a record and find the fields with a reference to sys_user

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it to work,

```
var grRecord = new GlideRecord('incident');
grRecord.get('284ec05bdbed2300ad8a2fb748961992');


var elements = grRecord.getElements();


for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
   var element = elements[i];

   try{
     if (element.getReferenceTable() == 'sys_user'){
        gs.info(element.getReferenceTable());
     }
   }

   catch(err){
      gs.info(err.message);
   }
}
```